# Process.Start does not always work

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I created a protocol generation tool that reads some data from a websource, allows the user to filter some of the fields an generate a protocol based on given filterdata. The protocol is generated as a word document that is edited multiple times, on multiple layers, before shown to the user.

For some users the line:

```
 Process.Start(pathtowordfile)
```

does not open Word, for others it works fine.

Even more strange: if the useres try to generate the protocol the first time it opens. if they change one of the filters and generate again, the file does not open. But it is generated correctly, you are able to open it manually.

We are using Windows 7 on all machines and, in general, the User has no administrativ privileges on the machine.

Are there any alternatives to

```
Process.Start()
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying varios things, including Wonko's hint, I dicided to use the interop.Word.Wordapplication to display the document. It doesn't explain why process.start not does the job but anyway, now everybody of the users is happy^^

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the code can sometimes work, but the critical bit I think would be to make sure you set UseShellExecute=true when you are trying to Process.Start a file that is not an executable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I haven't looked into it in quite awhile, but last I checked shell execute relies on the Word application to be properly registered with DDE so Windows knows what to do with a .doc(x) file. Word may not be installed "properly".